# How to remove tags that are with empty data in html in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4.2

#### HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1  style="text-align: center;">heading</h1>
<p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">this is first paragraph</div></p>
<p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;"></div></p>
<p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;"></div></p>
<p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">This is middle paragraph</div></p>
<p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;"></div></p>
<b><div  style="text-align: right;"></div></b>
</body></html>
```

How do I remove lines with empty tags so that I get the following output:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1  style="text-align: center;">heading</h1>
<p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">this is first paragraph</div></p>
<p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">This is middle paragraph</div></p>
</body></html>
```

How do I do this in Objective-C? Is there any method that can remove the empty tags when sent the actual htmlstring.

Comment: This is a real interesting question and I'd love to tackle it TDD style if I had some spare cycles. It would be lots of fun.

Comment: Apologies for speaking in fancy acronyms, Above I was referring to "Test Driven Design" (TDD).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to replace those lines with empty string:

```
NSString *htmlString = <YOUR_HTML_CODE>;
NSString *targetString = @"<p><div  style=\"padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;\"></div></p>";
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: targetString withString: @""];
```

Comment: This approach is very brittle and assumes that the empty tags will always look the same and would miss tags like: <p name="para1"><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;"></div></p> or tags like: <p><div  ></div></p>

Comment: Yes, I know that my code will work correctly only with Univer's HTML sample. But if somebody wants to detect ALL empty paragraph tags he should write it owns HTML parser (or use existing one).